# Can't connect to Mongo Atlas getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND [cluster name]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bots, slack, mongodb-atlas

Using Botkit to create slack bot but can't connect to Mongo Atlas for storage. Nodejs backend. Using Botkit-storage-mongo

Code:

```
var Botkit = require('botkit');
var BotkitStorage = require('botkit-storage-mongo');
storage = BotkitStorage({ mongoUri: `mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<clustername>/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`})
```

When I run the code I get this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: MongoError: failed to connect to server [<cluster_name>] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <cluster_name>
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26) {
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <cluster_name>'
}]
```

Dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "botkit": "0.6.21",
    "botkit-storage-mongo": "1.0.7",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.0"
  }
```

In Mongo Atlas, 
my IP address is whitelisted. 
Also tested allowing all IPs: 0.0.0.0/0.

Any ideas as to why I cannot connect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue had nothing to do with botkit.

Needed to update connection driver version in mongo atlas dashboard.

Was Node.js 3.0 or later driver version. When I changed that to the Node.js 2.2.12 or later version, that connection string worked.