# KeystoneJS V4 app that used to work when deploying to Heroku is now stopped working - MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, keystonejs

A KeystoneJS V4 app which was running & working perfectly connected to MongoDB Atlas few months ago was deleted by Heroku due to some stack change. Now I'm trying to deploy the same app with correct configurations but there's a deployment error. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
2021-06-23T17:14:40.418968+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-23T17:14:43.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-06-23T17:14:46.464645+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node keystone.js`
2021-06-23T17:14:49.588440+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2021-06-23T17:14:49.588949+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2021-06-23T17:14:49.588950+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2021-06-23T17:14:49.711527+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------------------------------------------
2021-06-23T17:14:49.711682+00:00 app[web.1]: Mongoose connection "error" event fired with:
2021-06-23T17:14:49.712891+00:00 app[web.1]: Error [MongoError]: failed to connect to server [cluster-1z703hln.tt6wq.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect
2021-06-23T17:14:49.712894+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:326:35)
2021-06-23T17:14:49.712894+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
2021-06-23T17:14:49.712894+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:272:12)
2021-06-23T17:14:49.712895+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
2021-06-23T17:14:49.712895+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
2021-06-23T17:14:49.712896+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:175:49)
2021-06-23T17:14:49.712896+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
2021-06-23T17:14:49.712897+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
2021-06-23T17:14:49.712897+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
2021-06-23T17:14:49.712897+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
2021-06-23T17:14:49.712899+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
2021-06-23T17:14:49.713715+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: KeystoneJS (My-App) failed to start - Check that you are running `mongod` in a separate process.
2021-06-23T17:14:49.713716+00:00 app[web.1]:     at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/openDatabaseConnection.js:59:10)
2021-06-23T17:14:49.713716+00:00 app[web.1]:     at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:314:20)
2021-06-23T17:14:49.713717+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Immediate.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:296:19)
2021-06-23T17:14:49.713717+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
2021-06-23T17:14:49.801512+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-06-23T17:14:49.940361+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-23T17:14:49.950336+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-23T17:14:57.803099+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node keystone.js`
2021-06-23T17:15:02.052669+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-06-23T17:15:02.247835+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-23T17:15:01.788675+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2021-06-23T17:15:01.788702+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2021-06-23T17:15:01.788703+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2021-06-23T17:15:01.971420+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------------------------------------------
2021-06-23T17:15:01.971542+00:00 app[web.1]: Mongoose connection "error" event fired with:
2021-06-23T17:15:01.975012+00:00 app[web.1]: Error [MongoError]: failed to connect to server [cluster-1z703hln.tt6wq.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect
2021-06-23T17:15:01.975013+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:326:35)
2021-06-23T17:15:01.975014+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
2021-06-23T17:15:01.975014+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:272:12)
2021-06-23T17:15:01.975014+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
2021-06-23T17:15:01.975015+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
2021-06-23T17:15:01.975015+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:175:49)
2021-06-23T17:15:01.975016+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
2021-06-23T17:15:01.975016+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
2021-06-23T17:15:01.975016+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
2021-06-23T17:15:01.975017+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
2021-06-23T17:15:01.975017+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
2021-06-23T17:15:01.975867+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: KeystoneJS (My-APP) failed to start - Check that you are running `mongod` in a separate process.
2021-06-23T17:15:01.975868+00:00 app[web.1]:     at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/openDatabaseConnection.js:59:10)
2021-06-23T17:15:01.975868+00:00 app[web.1]:     at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:314:20)
2021-06-23T17:15:01.975868+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Immediate.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:296:19)
2021-06-23T17:15:01.975869+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
```

Can someone help me with this please. Not sure why I'm getting this error. I have the correct MONGODB_URI (which works fine on another app).

Answer (score 0):

That error (`failed to connect to server`) is coming straight from Mongoose so it's a problem with the DB connection. The cause is probably either...

**Networking**

Atlas blocks all traffic by default; for Heroku deploys you need to open it up by configuring the [access list](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security/ip-access-list). In this case it should contain something like `0.0.0.0/32` to allow all IPs. (I know you said the DB is accessible from another app but still worth checking.)

**Auth**

Does the URI contain the username password? It should be in the form...

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster-1z703hln.tt6wq.mongodb.net/my-app?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

.. or similar, ***not*** the shorter form that Atlas suggests for the CLI, eg.

```
mongodb+srv://cluster-1z703hln.tt6wq.mongodb.net/my-app
```

What happens when you attempt to connect from `mongo` client on your dev machine? It may give a more helpful error message.

Comment: Thank you. 
Networking - Yes, it already configured to database access with 0.0.0.0/0 to allow all IPs.
Auth - Yes, the URI is in the correct format with correct UN & PW. The same one used to access the other app. The only difference is, one of the previous error suggested to remove the +srv. So it starts with mongodb:// - I had this issue previously and after removing +srv only it let connect to the DB.

Comment: @billgajen You mean `0.0.0.0/32` right? `0.0.0.0/0` will block everything. Other than that, I'm out of ideas. Did you try connecting from a Mongo client (like the mongo cli) on your dev machine?

Comment: Hi @molomby, Finally this answer helped resolve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59778351/cant-connect-to-mongo-atlas-getaddrinfo-enotfound-cluster-name . Thank you